# How to grey out fields with non editable permission upon node editing?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I need the ability to grey out fields with non editable permission i.e. to show certain field values to the user but forbid him/her to edit them, upon node editing.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You mean readonly field ?

Comment: Are you using D7 or D6 ?

Comment: Exactly. Field permissions give the ability to leave unchecked the "edit own field" permission but this results to hiding the field. I want that field to be readonly as a reminder for the user. Using D7...

Answer (score 2):

[Form elements have a `disabled` property](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html) you can set as a boolean. For example:

```
$form['test'] = array(
  '#type' => 'text',
  '#title' => t('Test'),
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#default_value' => 0,
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
);
```

Now, you can use `hook_form_alter()` to check that you're on the right form (`$form_id`), and any other conditions you require, like for instance checking user permissions, with the `user_access()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fastest way to achieve what You want is to use jQuery in Your template or custom module:

```
$("#fieldName").prop("readonly",true);
```